# Merging multiple images as one in PHP - slow function

Tags: php, image, merge

I'm new here so this will be my first post!

I have this function below, that is merging four images into one. It works, but it takes almost 20 seconds. Is there any way to speed this up? Grateful for all help!

```
<?php

$images = $_GET['i']; 
$nb = $_GET['nb']; 

if ($nb == '4') { 
   $dest = imagecreatefrompng('files/template_collage_' . $nb . '.png'); 
    $image_files = explode('|', $images); 
    $i = 1; 

    foreach ($image_files as $image_file) { 

        $image_source = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_file); 
        $size = getimagesize($image_file); 
        $image_new = imagecreatetruecolor(612,612); 
        imagecopyresampled($image_new,$image_source,0,0,0,0,612,612,$size[0],$size[1]); 

        if ($i == 1) { 
            imagecopymerge($dest, $image_new, 0, 0, 0, 0, 612, 612, 100); 

        } else if ($i == 2) { 
            imagecopymerge($dest, $image_new, 612, 0, 0, 0, 612, 612, 100); 

        } else if ($i == 3) { 
            imagecopymerge($dest, $image_new, 0, 612, 0, 0, 612, 612, 100); 

        } else if ($i == 4) { 
            imagecopymerge($dest, $image_new, 612, 612, 0, 0, 612, 612, 100); 

        } 

        $i++; 

        imagedestroy($image_source); 
        imagedestroy($image_new); 
        $size = ''; 
    } 


    // Output and free from memory 
    header('Content-Type: image/png'); 
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=collage_card.png'); 
    imagejpeg($dest, null, 100); 

    imagedestroy($dest); 


}  

?>
```

**AN UPDATE BELOW:**

I changed to imagecopyresampled and got rid of $image_new. Still no improvement, it's about 4.5 seconds for each loop.

```
<?php

if ($nb == '4') {

$dest = imagecreatefrompng('files/template_collage_' . $nb . '.png');
$image_files = explode('|', $images);
$i = 1;

foreach ($image_files as $image_file) {

    $image_source = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_file);
    $size = getimagesize($image_file);

    if ($i == 1) {
        imagecopyresampled($dest, $image_source, 0, 0, 0, 0, 612, 612, $size[0],$size[1]);

    } else if ($i == 2) {
        imagecopyresampled($dest, $image_source, 612, 0, 0, 0, 612, 612, $size[0],$size[1]);

    } else if ($i == 3) {
        imagecopyresampled($dest, $image_source, 0, 612, 0, 0, 612, 612, $size[0],$size[1]);

    } else if ($i == 4) {
        imagecopyresampled($dest, $image_source, 612, 612, 0, 0, 612, 612, $size[0],$size[1]);

    }

    $i++;

    imagedestroy($image_source);
    $size = '';
}


// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=collage_card.jpg');
imagejpeg($dest, null, 100);

imagedestroy($dest);


}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the intermediate `$image_new`:

```
if ($i == 2) {
  imagecopyresampled($dest, $image_source,
    612, 0,           // target position
    0, 0,             // source position
    612, 612,         // target size
    $size[0],$size[1] // source size
  );
}
```

Also, if a complex operation takes too long, the first step is to measure which part of the complex operation is actually responsible for that. Some well placed calls to [`microtime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) will help you with that.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Oswald! The reason for $image_new is that the source image is sometimes larger than 612. If i don't use it and the source image is larger, then it's cropped on the right and bottom side. Is there any other way to solve that?

Comment: That's odd, the [documentation for `imagecopyresampled()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) does not say anything about cropping. Are you sure you looked at the correct documentation page?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! I have edited my post above with the updated code. Still the same problem. The most time consuming seems to be imagecreatefromjpeg() and getimagesize(). Is there any way to improve that?

Comment: What do you mean by *seems to be*? Did you meassure or didn't you measure? If `getimagesize()` takes too long, use [`imagesx()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesx.php) and its vertical sibling to determine the size of the image. This avoids parsing the image file twice.

Comment: I did measured it. I replaced getimagesize() with imagesx() and imagesy() and it reduced the total load time from around 17 seconds to around 8 seconds. Out of those 8 seconds, imagecreatefromjpeg() is about 5 seconds now.

Comment: In other words, each loop takes about 2 seconds, and most of that time is imagecreatefromjpeg();. The rest is loading fast. Can imagecreatefromjpeg() be replaced with something faster?

Comment: Next thing I would try is to parallelize the loading. But that's cumbersome in PHP and I don't know what GD thinks about it.